# Is it possible to use annotation as a dynamic goal line?

Tags: javascript, api, chart.js

Can (Chart.js) annotation be used as a dynamic "goal line" where the annotation value adjusts based on some easy rules and chart data?

For example, if I run a minimum of 10km, 3 weeks in a row, the annotation goal line increases by +6km; the same applies to the next level. If I do not manage to run 10km for the last 3 weeks it lowers the down to 8km; I think you get the logic. The goal adjust dynamically based on the previous 3 weeks of data.

Made a visualization: [how I imagine how it could be looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGvu.png)

Ps. I am a noob. I have no clue what is needed to finalize this idea.

Best regards

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chart.js, the Missing Manual</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(75, 192, 192, 1);
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 800px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(75, 192, 192, 1);
        background: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chartMenu">
      <p>Hi there</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.1.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-Tfw6etYMUhL4RTki37niav99C6OHwMDB2iBT5S5piyHO+ltK2YX8Hjy9TXxhE1Gm/TmAV0uaykSpnHKFIAif/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="path/to/chartjs-plugin-annotation/dist/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // data block
    var week = [], kilometer = [], pushups = [], situps = []
    
    

    async function dummyChart () {
    await getDummyData()

    const data = {
      labels: week.slice(-8),
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Kilometer',
        data: kilometer.slice(-8),
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
          offset: 5,
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
          },
          clamp: true,
        },
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
    };

    // config block
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
              },   
        },
        layout: {
          padding: 20,
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
         },
          autocolors: false,
          annotation: {
           annotations: {
            line1: {
             type: 'line',
             yMin: 10,
             yMax: 10,
             borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
             borderWidth: 2,
          }
        }
      }
    }
      },
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
    };
     // init render block
     const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
  }
  dummyChart()

    // Fetch data from API
    async function getDummyData() {
      const apiUrl = "https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/an675a1pxghf6?sheet=Strava:weekly"

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
      const lineChartData = await response.json()
     
      const weekdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.week)
      const kilometerdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.kilometer)
      const pushupsdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.pushups)
      const situpsdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.situps)
    
    
      console.log(kilometerdata.slice(-4), pushupsdata, situpsdata)

      kilometer = kilometerdata
      pushups = pushupsdata
      situps = situpsdata
      week = weekdata

    }


   
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently with chartjs-plugin-annotation, this is not doable. Maybe you add a dataset (with stepped: false) and you add a label (by chartjs-plugin-annotation to show "Goal")

Comment: It is possible, you just need to go into the options object, change the config of the annotation and then call update on the chart

Comment: I don't think the line annotation can do what is asked here. Maybe I'm wrong. Only with multiple annotation (2 lines) but it depends on how much dynamic should be.

Comment: Created a codepen with a specific dataset with goals and used a label annotation. https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/xxjxpVr Maybe can help

Comment: @user2057925, You are brilliant. THANKS! How are the goals logically built up on this script?

Comment: yes, inside the block "for (let i = 0; i < ds.data.length; i++)" where the data are scanned